# seajs require cause incompatible in IE7

Tags: javascript

I use seajs,and my project compatible in IE8,chrome,safari,firefox but it does's compatible in IE7
[image: On IE7]

[image: It's said that ‘Missing identifier, string, or number’，‘router is empty or not an object’]

It's said that ‘Missing identifier, string, or number’，‘router is empty or not an object’

Comment: You have to support IE7?...that's a bummer.

Comment: yes,I don't know how to do